# How to configure intellij to find spring properties source

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm looking for a way to follow source of spring configuration from annotation.
E.g. Having below Bean is any way to e.g. click on `my-components-service.books.configurations` and be redirect or list yaml files which contains config which would be injected in runtime?

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-components-service.books.configurations")
Map<ComponentType, BooksConfiguration> booksConfiguration() {
  return new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but i think It Is in the paid version of intellij, are you using the community?

Comment: I use paid one - Ultimate 2019.03

Answer (score 0):

If `@ConfigurationProperties` is at the class level then there should be some gutter icons that will show where the properties have been set.
[image: IntelliJ spring boot properties gutter popup]

It doesn't look like this works when it's specified on a `@Bean` like in your example however. A possible workaround is to use a nested `@Configuration` class, though that may be undesirable.
[image]